# Dynamically Adding data to jagged array?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a recursive function that creates a list of items based on their hierarchy(integer is used to determine which level 1 to 10 max). There can be x number of items in any given level. I want to store all the items that belong the same level at the corresponding index of the jagged array. The items aren't retrieved based on their level so the level can be jumping around all of over the place as the function recurses.

```
    Function RecurseParts(lngPartID1, lngLevel) As Object
        'this function will recursivley print the parts lists for the part ID passed in


        If IsNumeric(lngPartID1 & "") Then
            Dim objRSTemp As Object = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

            objRSTemp.CursorLocation = adUseClient
            objRSTemp.Open(PART_LIST_SQL & lngPartID1, objConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly)
            'objRSTemp.ActiveConnection = Nothing

            If objRSTemp.eof And objRSTemp.bof Then
                'PROBLEM, WE HAVE NO RECORDS
                Response.Write("There Were No Parts For This Assembly (Part ID #:" & lngPartID1 & ")")
            Else
                'make output    

                Dim strTemp As String = String.Empty
                If lngLevel <> 1 Then strTemp = " style=""display: none;"">"
                Response.Write("<table id='tblparts" & lngCurrentLineNum & "' border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""100%"" cellpadding=""1"" " & strTemp)

                Do Until objRSTemp.EOF


                    'increase the current line num 
                    lngCurrentLineNum = lngCurrentLineNum + 1

                    'get current Part ID
                    lngCurrentPartID = objRSTemp("PartID").value

                    'reset flag
                    blnIsAssm = False

                    'loop thru array of assemblies to see if this is a parent 
                    For ctr = 0 To UBound(arrAssmList, 2)
                        If arrAssmList(0, ctr) = lngCurrentPartID Then
                            'the current part is an assembly
                            blnIsAssm = True
                            Exit For
                        ElseIf arrAssmList(0, ctr) > lngCurrentPartID Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    If blnIsAssm Then
                      'recurse these parts
                        If RecurseParts(objRSTemp("PartID").value, lngLevel + 1) = True Then
                            'awesome
                        End If

                    End If

                    objRSTemp.MoveNext()
                Loop
                Response.Write("</table>")
            End If

            If objRSTemp.State Then objRSTemp.Close()
            objRSTemp = Nothing

            'RETURN FUNCTION
            RecurseParts = True
        Else
            'no PART ID passed in
            Response.Write("No Part ID Passed In")
            RecurseParts = False
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: What dataTypes are you wanting to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a List to store all the partIDs and their levels.

```
 Dim arrSubID As New List(Of List(Of Integer))()
Function RecurseParts(paramenters) 
   For ctr = 0 To UBound(arrAssmList, 2)
                            If arrAssmList(0, ctr) = lngCurrentPartID Then
                              'checks whether we need a new index in the list
                                If lngLevel + 1 > arrSubID.Count Then
                                    arrSubID.Add(New List(Of Integer))
                                End If
                                'adds the partID where it belongs!
                                arrSubID(lngLevel).Add(lngCurrentPartID)

                                blnIsAssm = True
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf arrAssmList(0, ctr) > lngCurrentPartID Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a `Dictionary` would work here.

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
```

In your recursive function. The parts in the {} are the parts you have to supply.

```
'this builds the keys as you go 
If Not myDict.ContainsKey({{key} -> your Integer}) Then
   'add key and use the From statement to add a value if know at this time
   myDict.Add({key}, New List(Of String) From {value})
Else
   myDict({key}).Add({string to insert at this level})
End If
```

List of keys in reverse order:

```
Dim keys = myDict.Keys.OrderByDescending(Function(k) k)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, really appreciate it! If I use a dictionary, can I iterate through it based on the level number. The reason why I wanted a jagged array was to iterate through all the items in every single level. Also, I didn't fully understand how I would use the dictionary.

Comment: You can iterate thru any level. If you tell me the second datatype I can fix my example.

Comment: I also need to see where the values are coming from. Can you show me the recursive method?

Comment: The level is simply an integer value, the part ID will also be an integer and I can save it either as an integer or string.

Comment: Not sure where to add that. The key of the dictionary should be the part number since duplicates are not allowed for dictionaries keys, then just add the values you find to the value part which is the `myDict({key}).Add()` part - this assigns the value to a particular key.

Comment: I need to be able to sort the partID by their level number because I will be putting the array(preferably) in a backwards loop starting from the greatest level number. I would prefer to have all the partIDs that belong to level(index) 1 to be together and so on. When it comes time to use that variable holding the info, I can use the highest level as my level knowing it is the sub assembly that has no other sub assemblies.

Comment: You can always query this Dictionary in many ways. I gave an example of getting keys by reverse order.

Comment: It refuses to take the integer value for {key} and complains that an array of integers cannot be converted to an integer. That is not the case, the variable lngLevel is simply an integer and I even tried storing its value in a new variable and using that and I got the same error.
myDict.Add({key}, New List(Of String) From {value}) .. it also says VB does not support this type of initialization. :(

Comment: You have to remove the braces from the key. Braces after the From statement is correct.